# ERROR in ./node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js

Tags: angular

I'm working with an angular project. I had been faced to an error while start the project by using `npm-start` command. I will show the error in below.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@firebase/firestore' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\firebase\firestore\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/array/find' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/array/find-index' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/object/assign' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/string/repeat' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/string/starts-with' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/symbol' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/dist/index.esm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/features/symbol/iterator' in 'C:\Users\ruwan\Documents\projects\new project\Hair-4-U-hospital\Admin\Hair-4-U-Manufacture\node_modules\@firebase\polyfill\dist'
```

So what is the cause for the error. I can't understanding that what was happen. The project was working in correctly.

Comment: what is the version of firebase + angularfire are you using?  please check it `"firebase": "^5.0.4"`,
`"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",`

Comment: I had installed `"@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",` by using `npm i --save @angular/fire firebase`

Comment: used this  `npm init` &
`npm install --save firebase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you have something missing, please run npm install in the root of the project and try again.